# Docusign: Do I need to call 'login' for every signing request?

Tags: docusignapi

I know that you have to call 'login' to receive your accountId & baseUrl before proceeding with a signing request.  However, I'm wondering if that's required for every request that my application makes over its lifetime?  Are those values (accountId & baseUrl) going to change or once I have them, can I hardcode them and skip calling login?  One less call over the wire, means a faster response for my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call those all the time.  My recommendation is to call that on user setup and then call it again only when login fails or the user wants to reset their credentials.

The reasons why existing logged in users's API calls might fail are:

1. user can close an account
2. the credentials might change
3. if you are using tokens the tokens might get revoked

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mike!  For us - our users aren't creating Docusign accounts, we'll be using the embedded feature to allow them to sign docs.  So based on your info, the only time the login would fail is if I change our docusign credentials, at which point I can update that values.  Thanks for your insights!